# What linux distro & platform and package capabilities is this device using?

Tags: embedded, devices, android, arm, distributions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrTpWlkupUs

Miracast Device, using a compact Linux distro.

Thoughts on how to dissect/ figure this out? Maybe Replicate?

- Is it using a certain Linux Distro in an Embedded fashion, on chip or using some kind of ARM processor?